# UIView inputView slide animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikeyboard, inputview

1. I've got UIView (implementing UIKeyInput) with custom inputView. I want to display this inputView as soon as whole view is visible, however there's slide animation after it's becoming first responder. Can I disable this animation and show inputView right away?
2. I am able to move this inputView up and down when I am doing long press on it. How can I disable it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way to accomplish this. However converting inputView to childViewController was straightforward and it hasn't got any limitations.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this, facing similar problem

Comment: I had custom UIView class which was set as a inputView property. Since I didn't find any answer for my questions, I simply wrapped this view inside UIViewController and set it as child view controller on bottom of my screen. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]` to disable the default animation before you call `becomeFirstResponder`.